# Merge 2 dataframes on Days and Month

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the following dataframes:

```
print(df1)

day   month   quantity   Operation_type
21     6         6           2
24     6         4           2
...

print(df2)
day   month   quantity  Operation_type 
22     6         10          1
23     6         15          1
...
```

I would like to get the following dataset:

```
print(final_df)

day   month   quantity  Operation_type 
21     6         6             2
22     6         10            1
23     6         15            1
24     6         4             2
...
```

I tried using:

`final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on=['day','month'])` but it creates a huge dataset and does not seem to be working properly;

Furthermore, if day and month are the same, I would like to paste the line whose `Operation_type == 2` before the one with `==1`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To combine the DataFrames into one, you don't want merge, you want `pd.concat`. To get the ordering properly, just use `DataFrame.sort_values`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by=['day', 'month', 'Operation_type'], 
    ascending=[True, True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an outer merge to achieve this result.

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer').sort_values('day')

#    day  month  quantity  Operation_type
# 0   21      6         6               2
# 2   22      6        10               1
# 3   23      6        15               1
# 1   24      6         4               2
```